# Bug or feature? Missing closing quote in Tcl is rarely seen as syntactically incorrect.

Tags: tcl

I tried it with Tcl 8.3 and 8.5: The statement

```
puts X"
```

is syntactically correct and outputs just an X and a double quote. I would have expected, that Tcl complains about a missing closing quote. OTOH, if I enter the statements

```
puts "X
```

and

```
puts "
```

in a tclsh, the statement is not executed yet, but tcls expects me to continue the string in the next line.

Which syntactic rule is hinding behind what looks like an anomaly to me?

Comment: Simplest way I'd see to output "x would be to `puts \"x`

Comment: Of course this works, but this was not my question. I'm interested in where it is defined, that a quote at the end of the line is considered a literal quote (i.e. doesn't need to be escaped), but the other ones aren't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not think it is a bug, as stated in documentation: [reference here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M7)

> [3] Words.
>   Words of a command are separated by white space (except for newlines, which are command separators).
>
> [4] Double quotes.
>   If the first character of a word is double-quote (“"”) then the word is terminated by the next double-quote character. If semi-colons, close brackets, or white space characters (including newlines) appear between the quotes then they are treated as ordinary characters and included in the word. Command substitution, variable substitution, and backslash substitution are performed on the characters between the quotes as described below. The double-quotes are not retained as part of the word.

The key part would be **If the first character of a word is double-quote (“"”) then the word is terminated by the next double-quote character.**

So in your case if word begins with `"` than closing double quote is expected, if word does not begins with `"` than such `"` is treated as part of the word not as something special as syntax for variables substitution.